# FrontController with RequestFactory in GWT

Tags: gwt, requestfactory, front-controller

I am using RequestFactory with GWT. It all working fine. I have a RequestContext interface that point to my DAO methodes.

Now I want to implement some kind of security check before calling the DAO. The first thing that comes to my mind is to use a FrontController and centralize the security in it, but I don't know to implement it with the RequestFactory. Any thought ?

Comment: What kind of security check do you want to make? Test User Authentification?

Comment: Basically I want to check if the user have an active session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I implemented the security checking:

On the server side I check to see that every `RequestFactory` request is associated with a user who has previously logged in. To do this, the `web.xml` file (in the war/WEB-INF directory) must have a mapping for the servlet class. Here's the entry from the `web.xml` file:

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>requestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.greatlogic.rfexample2.server.RFERequestFactoryServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>symbolMapsDirectory</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/symbolMaps/</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>requestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The `RFERequestFactoryServlet` class contains the following code:

```java
public class RFERequestFactoryServlet extends RequestFactoryServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
  throws IOException, ServletException {
  if (!userIsLoggedIn(request)) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
  }
  else {
    super.doPost(request, response);
  }
}

private boolean userIsLoggedIn(final HttpServletRequest request) {
  boolean result = false;
  HttpSession session = request.getSession();
  if (session != null) {
    User user = (User)session.getAttribute("User");
    result = user != null;
  }
  return result;
}

}
```

On the client side I needed to intercept every `RequestFactory` response to check for the `SC_UNAUTHORIZED` error. You have to tell the `RequestFactory` object to use a specific `RequestTransport` in the `RequestFactory#initialize` invocation, like this:

```java
MyRequestFactory requestFactory = GWT.create(MyRequestFactory.class);
requestFactory.initialize(eventBus, new RFERequestTransport());
```

My `RFERequestTransport` class extends the `DefaultRequestTransport` class:

```java
public class RFERequestTransport extends DefaultRequestTransport {

private final class RFERequestCallback implements RequestCallback {

private RequestCallback _requestCallback;

private RFERequestCallback(final RequestCallback requestCallback) {
  _requestCallback = requestCallback;
}

@Override
public void onError(final Request request, final Throwable exception) {
  _requestCallback.onError(request, exception);
}

@Override
public void onResponseReceived(final Request request, final Response response) {
  if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
    // the login processing goes here
  }
  else {
    _requestCallback.onResponseReceived(request, response);
  }
}

} // end of the RFERequestCallback class

@Override
protected RequestCallback createRequestCallback(final TransportReceiver receiver) {
  return new RFERequestCallback(super.createRequestCallback(receiver));
}

}
```

When `RequestFactory` creates a request callback it calls my method, which creates my own version of a `RequestCallback`. If the user is logged in (as determined by the servlet) then it just performs the normal `RequestFactory` processing; otherwise, I go through the login process with the user. Part of the login process involves communication with the server to verify the login ... if the login is successful then I create an object on the server and store a reference to it in the "User" attribute - this is then checked in the `userIsLoggedIn` method in the servlet class.

Comment: How do you manage the first login request ? because the session is not created yet

Comment: @Moh In `RFERequestFactoryServlet#userIsLoggedIn` I am executing `HttpServletRequest#getSession`. The JavaDoc for this method states: Returns the current session associated with this request, or if the request does not have a session, creates one.

Comment: I understand the part for `HttpSession`. But when a user is fetched from the session, it can be null, that would be normal if no user has been logged in. Now my problem is when I call the method in the DAO that does the login, the call would be processed throught `RFERequestFactoryServlet#userIsLoggedIn` and because there is no user in the session yet, the login request wouldn't go throught and the login view will be displayed. How to let the login request go throught even no user is in the session ?

Comment: @Moh Are you concerned that there is a loop in the process ... that is, when you process the user's response to the login request is processed it will just cause another `SC_UNAUTHORIZED` response from the servlet? (btw, please use the "@" in your comments so that I see them in email).

Comment: @Moh I don't know whether this will help, but in my code that implements the login process I send the user's username and password using GWT RPC, and not using `RequestFactory`, that is, I don't use a DAO for logging in. I have an example project that implements this scheme (although it doesn't include actions for failed logins in this example) ... I describe the project in my blog, [here](http://greatlogic.com/?p=264).

Comment: Yes I was concerned by the loop problem...Finally I did the login process in a servlet separately. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test whether the user is authenticated, you can use a servlet filter on the server-side and a custom `RequestTransport` on the client-side. See the `guice-rf-activity` archetype at https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes for an example.

You can also check on the method-level by using a custom [`ServiceLayerDecorator`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/ServiceLayerDecorator.html) and implementing the `invoke` method, calling `report()` when the user isn't authorized/authenticated (and handling the `onFailure` on the client-side). I implemented such a thing, that authorized the user based on [`@RolesAllowed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html) annotations on the service method or class: https://gist.github.com/tbroyer/6091533

Answer (score 1):

Setup a filter in your web.xml so as every RF request is filtered to validate the session.

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>my.namespace.AuthFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here you have an example class, checking if a certain parameter is in session which could be set in the login process to your app, this is just an example, you could use your own mechanism.

```java
  public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
        ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

      HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
      HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

      if (req.getSession().getAttribute("VALID_SESSION") == null) {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        return;
      }

      if (null != filterChain) {
        filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
      }

    }
  }
```